# Thread die when the Controller return

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, structuremap

I am developing a heavy MVC routine that will delay some minutes to process. Then I call an Ajax request and I would like to send an answer from controller to interface if the process has started correctly and to keep executing it using a Thread. However, when the return is sent, it is needed to access the database, and I have the following error: Object disposed.

My code:

```
var entidade = this._repositorioDeTabelaDePremiacaoUPL.ObterPorID(dto.ID);
if(entidade.StatusDoServico == ListaDeStatusDoServico.tcProcessando.Id)
     return Content("{success:false}");

Thread thread = new Thread(() => this._servicoDeTabelaDePremiacaoUPL.GerarTabela(dto));
thread.Start();
GerenciadorDeUnidadeDeTrabalho.Corrente.Commit();

return Content("{success:true}");
```

Comment: How do you manage the lifecycle of database context? Are you creating new instances on your own, or do you use some DI container for it?

Comment: @mipe34, my database context is full loaded inside the global.asax, where all instances are loaded.

Comment: *full loaded inside the global.asax* - You have one dbContext per whole application lifecycle stored in some static property? Please show me the code where the `this._repositorioDeTabelaDePremiacaoUPL` is set? Could you also post the code of db context initialization in `global.asax`?

Comment: @mipe34, my db context inicialization in global.axax is done through structure map like that:

`ObjectFactory.Configure(i =>
            {
 i.For<ContextoBase>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use<ContextoDaAplicacao>();
}`

My method this._repositorioDeTabelaDePremiacaoUPL is very big to put here.

Comment: Please post updates into your question.

Comment: @mipe34, my db context inicialization in global.axax is done through structure map like that:

`ObjectFactory.Configure(i =>
            {
 i.For<ContextoBase>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use<ContextoDaAplicacao>();
}`

My method this._repositorioDeTabelaDePremiacaoUPL is very big to put here.

I have a dbContext per whole application lifeciche, and it is static.
It is stored on the variable `GerenciadorDeUnidadeDeTrabalho.Corrente`.

Comment: The error source is the created thread or action method? I can guess that your db context is somehow disposed before the thread ends... Anyway, it is not very good idea to share one db context per application lifecycle. You can have concurrency issues, when there will be multiple requests on your site. PS. Why do you use DI container (structure map) when you are not actually using it. Register your db context with http context lifecycle and use constructor injection inside your controllers.

Comment: @mipe34, The error source happens in Action method...After my controller returns, my method tries to access the database, then the error is triggered.

Comment: It does not make sense. If it happens after your controller returns. Then it could not be inside action method but i guess it is inside the thread. Look at my answer, if it could help you. But, I see problem in your app design, which could be wired to anothere problems, not easy to find out, where they are comming from. See my notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use an extra db context for your thread and dispose it at the end. Because your db context for your web application and extra thread have different lifecycles. For web application it is generealy per HttpContext - web request and for thread is it the lifespan of the thread. You can create new instance of your db context at own or use some [Conditional object construction](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2009/01/19/conditional-object-construction-in-structuremap-i-e-fun-with-lambdas/).

*Notes:*

*It is not a very good practice to reuse your db context for whole lifecycle of your application and reference it as static property (it could lead in concurrency issues and the entities state inside the context could become inconsistent). Better approach is to register your db context in HTTPContext scope (`InstanceScope.HttpContext`) and then use constructor injection on your controllers.*

**Global.asax**

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(i => { i.For<ContextoBase>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.HttpContext)).Use<ContextoDaAplicacao>(); }
```

**Controller**

```
public MyController(ContextoBase context){
    this.context = context;
}
// then use it in action methods (note: it will be automatically disposed at the end of the web request)
```